# GULP: set variables or arguments

Tags: gulp

I've this snippet code:

```
gulp.src('src/index-public.html').pipe(rename('index.html'))
    .pipe(replace("<base href='/'>", function(match) {
        return'<base href="/web/">'
    }))
```

As you can see I'm replacing `"base href='/'>"` by `"base href='/web'"`.

I need to replace `"base href='/'>"` by `"base href='/${ARGUMENT OR ENV VARIABLE}'"`

I've tried using `gulp --basehref "web"` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use environment variables

On Windows

```
set GULP_BASEHREF=web
```

On Linux / OSX

```
export GULP_BASEHREF=web
```

Then in your task

```
const baseHref = (process.env.GULP_BASEHREF || 'web').trim().toLowerCase();

gulp.src('src/index-public.html').pipe(rename('index.html'))
    .pipe(replace("<base href='/'>", function(match) {
        return '<base href="/' + baseHref + '">'
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use a package like

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
const argv = yargs.argv;

gulp.task('default', function () {

  return gulp.src('rawData/data.txt')

    .pipe(replace("asdasd", function (match) {

      // Usage:  gulp --basehref web

      console.log("3 = " + process.argv[2]);         // --basehref
      console.log("4 = " + process.argv[3]);         // web

      console.log("basehref = " + argv.basehref);    // web

      return '<base href="' + argv.basehref + '">';
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("rawData"));
  });
```

Usage : `gulp --basehref web`

Substitute your `src` and `dest` locations and other parts of the pipe.